# Parsing params that includes json string in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, react-native

In a react-native app, I have the following post request that goes to a rails controller

```
  fetch(POST_PAID_UP, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      receipt_num: 127,
      }).replace(/{|}/gi, "")
  })
```

In the appropriate action of my rails controller I can examine params it looks like this;

```
{"\"receipt_num\":127"=>nil, "controller"=>"ios/accounts", "action"=>"create"}
```

so the data is being received. From params I need to extract the value of 'receipt_num'.  I have tried `JSON.parse(params)`, but I receive this error;

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

So how should I parse this data?

Comment: what `replace` is for?

Comment: See answer below that explains the ```replace```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add headers that indicate that the information being sent is of type json. So add the following hash to the fetch instruction;

```
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
```

You can then remove the `.replace(/{|}/gi, "")` which is just a work around to overcome the fact that you were not specifying the data was json. The final code should look like this:

```
  fetch(POST_PAID_UP, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }, 
    body: JSON.stringify({
      receipt_num: transactionIdentifier,
      })
  })
```

You can find more information about fetch  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer was actually very useful as is, but Robin Daugherty was correct that it could be improved. I have edited it to provide more detail about why/how. Maybe someone else, could add information on limitations and assumptions.